# Clock.schedule_once not updating the label, but update method is being called

Tags: user-interface, raspberry-pi, kivy, kivy-language

I have a label in which I need to update the text once I receive the text from server. Method is working, am getting the output and the function is also getting called, but the label text is not updating.

My code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jan 21 00:34:58 2019

@author: driftking9987
"""
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import requests
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
import time

url = 'http://119.........'
l_server_text = "abc..."
l_server_text_waiting = "def..."
l_server_text_error = "ghi..."
self_global = ""

class HBoxWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HBoxWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class VBoxWidget_Details(BoxLayout):
    label_name = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(VBoxWidget_Details, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.label_name = l_server_text


    def updateText(self, *args):
        print("string to be updated is : ")
        print(l_server_text)
        print("updated")
        self.label_name = l_server_text


class ContainerBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ContainerBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class WipApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global self_global
        self_global = self
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: retrieveDataFromServer(self_global,12), 2)
        return ContainerBox() 


def retrieveDataFromServer(self,id):
    global l_server_text
    l_server_text = l_server_text_waiting
    print(l_server_text)
    a = VBoxWidget_Details()
    a.updateText(self)
    try:
        r_headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        }
        data_post_req =  '{"id":'+str(id)+'}'
        print(data_post_req)
        response = requests.post('http://119....', headers=r_headers, data=data_post_req)
        res = response.json()
        output_text = res['Message']
        output_text = output_text.replace(':', '\n')
        print(output_text)
        l_server_text = output_text
        a = VBoxWidget_Details()
        a.updateText(self)
        print("done")
    except Exception as e:
        print("exception")
        l_server_text = l_server_text_error
        a = VBoxWidget_Details()
        a.updateText(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wapp = WipApp()
    wapp.run()
```

KV file :

```
<HBoxWidget>:

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        Image:
            source: '/Users/driftking9987/Desktop/fp.gif'
<VBoxWidget_Details>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size: [1,.25]
        pos: root.pos
        Label:
            id: label_name
            text: root.label_name
            color: [0,84,80,19]
        Widget:

<ContainerBox>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: 'Label'
        size_hint_y: 0.1
    BoxLayout:
        id: four_horizontals
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        HBoxWidget:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            BoxLayout:
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:'vertical'
                VBoxWidget_Details:
            BoxLayout:
```

Below is output in terminal :

```
driftking9987$ python pp.py 
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/driftking9987/.kivy/logs/kivy_19-01-21_47.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.8 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 29 2018, 19:04:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'2.1 INTEL-12.4.7'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics 650'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.20'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
def...
string to be updated is : 
def...
updated
{"id":12}
KAM TRY
 logout
 Contac
string to be updated is : 
KAM TRY
 logout
 Contac
updated
done
```

And on the Kivy App, all I see is `abc` is the label text.

I plan to call the `retrieveDataFromServer` recursively after some condition is satisfied and that should change the text but it's not happening.

Any idea?

*************************UPDATE****************************

Let's say I just want to reference the label with the id, then how do I do that?

```
<HBoxWidget>:

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        Image:
            source: '/Users/driftking9987/Desktop/fp.gif'
<VBoxWidget_Details>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size: [1,.25]
        pos: root.pos
        the_label_g_info: label_name
        Label:
            id: label_name
            text: root.label_name
            color: [0,84,80,19]
        Widget:

<ContainerBox>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    title_name: title
    Label:
        id: title
        text: 'Label'
        size_hint_y: 0.1
    BoxLayout:
        box_name: box_id
        id: four_horizontals
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        HBoxWidget:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            BoxLayout:
            BoxLayout:
                id: box_id
                the_label_g_info: label_name
                orientation:'vertical'
                VBoxWidget_Details:
            BoxLayout:
```

Inside the `updateText` method, if I try to write `self.the_label_g_info.text="drift"` , it says `AttributeError: 'wapp' object has no attribute 'the_label_g_info'`

I mean, how do I reference the label? I am trying from 2 days, nothing seems to fix this. At the same time, the `self.label_name = str(l_server_text)` inside `__init__` of `VBoxWidget_Details` seems to set the text correctly while initialising.

Comment: Sorry for a possibly silly question, but where is the `Label` that you are trying to update? I don't see one in your code.

Comment: @JohnAnderson, I didn't post the kv code but the `label_name = StringProperty()` inside `VBoxWidget_Details` is the label which am talking about.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your `retrieveDataFromServer()` method, I see:

```
    a = VBoxWidget_Details()
    a.updateText(self)
```

in two places. This code is creating a new `VBoxWidget_Details` instance and calling `updateText()` on that new instance rather than on the one you have displayed. You probably need to save a reference to the existing `VBoxWidget_Details` somewhere, and reference that instance in your `retrieveDataFromServer()` method.

Comment: In total there are three instance, one is in start, second is in try and third is in except. Even if am removing the ones in try and except, am getting the same error. Am just initialising it in starting of function and then calling `a.updateText(self)`

Comment: I missed one of them, so there are actually four instances. The three you mentioned and the one in your display (created by the `VBoxWidget_Details:` line in your `KV`). The one in your `KV` is the one being displayed, so that's the only instance you should reference.

Comment: In the `KV` am just referencing the text to `root.label_name` and in python while inside init, it's changing the text. Afterwards, am just creating a new instance(as mentioned by you). I don't think in `KV`, its creating any instance.

Comment: In the `KV` file your `<ContainerBox>:` provides a rule for creating a `ContainerBox`. When your `build()` method in `WipApp` calls `ContainerBox()`, that rule is followed and an instance of `VBoxWidget_Details` is created and displayed when the `WipApp` starts. Any other call to `VBoxWidget_Details()` creates a new and different instance of `VBoxWidget_Details` that is not displayed.