# Run a python function in parallel from kivy app and update the label

Tags: python, kivy, raspberry-pi3, kivy-language

I need to run a function from a python `fileA` which will update the label in the kivy app.

For example, in python `fileA` I am running a scanner function which basically first init the sensors and then start scanning. Then after the scan is completed, it again starts scanning. Basically a never ending loop.

Now in kivy, if am running that function by `from fileA import scFun` and then `scFun.init()`, the `init` function starts but the UI get's blocked.

How do I run the function in parallel and update the label in kivy app once the scan is complete.

Comment: Can you put on your code? Did you try with another thread?

Comment: It's exactly the same code, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54294930/clock-schedule-once-not-updating-the-label-but-update-method-is-being-called but am adding another function below that. The function from another file is basically reading `'/dev/ttyUSB0` in raspberry. Additional info : Am still not able to update the label in other question.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the function from kivy class(container)  in separate thread using threading library. Clock is for simple task that doesn't block your main thread. It is actually main thread. Request is blocking.

My advice is, as I revised you your mentioned code,  to do all logic in your container box layout. It's the parent of all and you can access all widgets from there.

Maybe best would be Clock schedule that would run function in intervals which would run your desired function in thread.